# Connecting to a modem in bridged mode wireless

Tags: wireless-router, modem

I've got a DSL modem configured in "bridged mode" with a wireless router initiating the login through the modem. The router's "Internet" port is wired to the modem's "LAN1" port.

Is it possible to achieve the same thing without a physical connection between the modem and the router? Meaning, can the router connect to the modem wirelessly, login, and still supply an internet connection to wireless clients?

### Why am I doing this?

My desktop computer used to be wired into the router that was wired into the modem. In my new house, the DSL demarcation point is located far from the desktop computer and the latter does not have a wireless network card. Ideally, I'd like to wire the desktop computer to the wireless router, then have the latter connect to the DSL modem wirelessly.

Comment: Why can't you configure the modem to do the (presumably) PPPoE login?

Comment: @DavidPostill The router runs dd-wrt so it has some bells and whistles that I'd like to use (e.g. connection watchdog). Even if I were to let the modem handle the PPPoE login, I still need the router to manage the wireless network as I'm using WDS to connect multiple routers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this wirelessly, do it with homeplugs instead. Run the pppoe connection over the homeplugs so you can put your router in a more suitable location. Make sure that the homeplugs are paired with their own security numbers as you don't want these to connect to other homeplugs if you get any more.

Comment: What about popping a wireless card into the desktop and leaving the router physically wired to the modem? Would you still recommend homeplugs over this option? If so, why?

Comment: Bandwidth, signal, interference. Wifi isnt as efficient. homeplugs would cope far better.